# Are there any tools to download "variable information list" file from AA?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

Are there any tools to download "variable information list" file from AA?
Or do we always have to check the codes in the atmx files to review the variable information ? 
Variable information means code row the variables are used in ,and the variable mapping from task to task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a degree it is possible to do what you are asking within AA. If you add a "Send Email" command to your script and then in the attachment section select 'attach all variables', which can be done by pressing the $ symbol.

When run it will email you with an attachment, which has a snapshot of all user and system variables at the time it was run, similar to what you can do with emails in the "Begin Error Handler" command. If you put it at the top it should show you the variables as per the script starting, if you add it at the end though it could be changed by any variable operations you have included in your script.

When documenting an automation I usually copy all the variables from all the scripts created into a new script with the method above, so i can get a list of all the variables used.

As de.Vina has already pointed out though, it is not best practice to hard code values into variables and it should be done via a configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revisit the best practices for Automation Anywhere.

Any values must not be stored in variables as default values. They should be stored in configuration files. (Format can be any of the following: Excel, CSV, XML, etc.) The advantage of this is that when you need to change any value, such as website URLs, you would only update the configuration files, and not your AA tasks. Another advantage of this is that when you test your codes, you won't have to check the values of each variable. You only need to check if those variables are mapped from task to task. Another best practice for this is to keep variable names the same on each task. This is for you to utilize the Quick Mapping option from Run Task command.

And to answer your question, variable values cannot be downloaded using third-party tools as it would be a security issue.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your advice. I really agree with what you told me. I actually do not hard cord the variable values, but control with using excel. The reason why i had the question above is i needed to documnet valiable lists for my client and thought it was gonna be hard work so... thank you so much anyway :)